# How can I let users specify which address is their preferred address (e.g. work or home) within a profile?

Tags: profile

When I'm using a profile that my users might be filling out for the first time (membership form for example), I generally ask for both a work and a home address, email address, etc. How can I let them choose which one to use as their primary contact information (mail and email as well as phone)?

Answer (score 1):

Adding as an answer since user never came back on this one.

This can be done via webform_civicrm for sites using Drupal where Location Type and Phone Type can be provided as 'user select' fields.

Answer (score 0):

What's more important for your organisation? Know that an address is primary? or that it is an home/work address?

If primary/secondary is more important then I would use the "Main" location type in the profile and set it to Primary in the settings. And then make sure a "secondary" Location type exists and add that one to the profile as well.

Comment: I definitely could do that, but CiviCRM also has a checkbox on the main contact edit screen that says Primary location for this contact and you can check that box to indicate which of their locations should be their primary location. That would be my solution, I just wish it could be exposed in a profile rather than only on the backend/backoffice section for a contact.

Comment: It can be done via webform_civicrm for sites using Drupal.